# How to access color from App.xaml in C# in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In App.xaml I have this code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Yellow">#ffd966</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and in C# I have this code:

```cs
public Color BackgroundColor
{
    get { return IsSelected ? Color.Yellow : Color.White; }
}
```

And I would like to change Color.Yellow with color from App.xaml. How can I reference color from App.xaml in C#?

Comment: isSelected ? (Color) Application.Current.Resources["Yellow"] : Color.White;

Comment: You can post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
isSelected ? (Color) Application.Current.Resources["Yellow"] : Color.White;
```

I think Conversion Color.FromHex() is not needed as you are defining resource as a color. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 21):

Just in case if the `Color` is referenced in `MergedDictionaries`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <resources:Colors />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

you'd need to get it like:

```cs
Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("Yellow", out var yellowColor)
```

If you use `Application.Current.Resources["Yellow"]` it will throw a key not found exception.

HIH

Comment: This should be the Top Answer because frankly everyone uses MergedDictionaries don't they?

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to access it like this `Application.Current.Resources["Yellow"]`.

In case of a color it would be more like;

```
public Color BackgroundColor
{
    get { return IsSelected ? Application.Current.Resources["Yellow"].ToString() : Color.White }
}
```